# Prisma 4 and prisma.$subscribe

Tags: prisma, subscribe, fastify, nexus-js

in Prisma 1 was really nice use of subscrition with prisma.$subscribe - [documentation](https://v1.prisma.io/docs/1.34/prisma-client/features/realtime-JAVASCRIPT-rsc8/). I look for same doc for Prisma@4.6 but in documentation is nothing about it and I found only notice that in Prisma@2 is still not implemented and maybe it will be there in future. Is there any body who know actual status how I can add to app this functionality? O what is correct place for include this now?
Dev stack:

- DB ORM: Prisma@4.6, db: sqlite
- Server: Fastify@4.9
- GraphQL generator: NexusJS

Thank a lot
Petr

Comment: I would go with [platformatic](https://oss.platformatic.dev/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prisma 2+ doesn't have native support for Prisma Subscriptions yet. There is a feature request for it here: [#298](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/298).

There are some alternatives suggested in the feature request, I would recommend you to have a look at them.

Comment: Thank a lot for useful answer. I hope that authors of Prisma finish some native support of this and until it I will use some alternative in link what you send.